# how to set the number of specific character matches before it stops?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm trying to learn more about regular expressions and I want to understand how to choose the number of characters regex will seek before it stops matching? for example:

I have the following string:

`>first)second)third)fourth)`

If I set regex as,

`>.*\)`

it will go all the way from ">" to the last ")", if I make it non-greedy like,

`>.*?\)`

it will stop at the first ")"

but how do I get the regex to stop at the second or third ")"?

I've tried something like,

`>.*\).*\)`

but it simply goes all the way to the end, how do I choose where to stop?

thank you in advance for the answers)

Comment: This is a rather broad question. The short answer, concerning the example you provided specifically, is to just use a lazy quantifier, and then either duplicate or quantify that whole sequence the number of times you want to match. `.*?\).*?\).*?\)` or `(?:.*?\)){3}` for example, to match up to the 3rd parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following regex to match respectively the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th, nth occurrences:

```
^>(?:[^)]*\))
^>(?:[^)]*\)){2}
^>(?:[^)]*\)){3}
^>(?:[^)]*\)){4}
^>(?:[^)]*\))*$
```

**demo**: https://regex101.com/r/ZEzYtM/2

You can just build this regex dynamically to match the ith occurrence.